# firebase App Check won't verify app in firestore in release mode but does in debug mode when app check is enforced on real device

Tags: android

So I implemented App check in my android studio project. And since it was a new app with no users I thought it best to enforce app check from the start. And I have no problem running the app if the app is running on debug mode. But when I create a release APK or bundle I app won't read anything from the Firebase Firestore or storage. What could be the problem? I follow all the steps required. I added the safetyNet dependence in my gradle and initialized the safetyNet Provider in my log in activity before calling any Firebase service.

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance();
firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
        SafetyNetAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance());
```

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you have used this remove these lines

```
release {
        minifyEnabled true
}
```

If not worked then add your SHA1 fingerprint that you get from playstore to the firebase console

Comment: thanks for your feedback but am still getting the same error rather still having the same problem

Answer (score -1):

add release sha1 key in firebase

Comment: so I added this, and also included the sha 256 in firebase that made it work. thank you very much for your help.